# Ipad application crashed when invoke CGContextDrawPDFPage

Tags: pdf, 2d, quartz-graphics

I have a pdf document with 1000 pages and I am drawing them using CGContextDrawPDFPage function. But on page 466 application crashed.
Here is my page drawing code...

```
 NSLog(@"%@",@"Before drawing pdf page.");
 CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);      
 NSLog(@"%@",@"After drawing pdf page.");
```

This is Console output:

```
2010-09-15 10:20:15.064 MYAPP[159:207] Before drawing pdf page.
Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
```

An I got this error only on a particular page. Btw on a simulator it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your application consume much memory. Try using:

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault); 
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _pdfPageCustom);              

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```